# How to prevent image jump after jquery scale effect

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/H3YHh/1

I am trying to scale up a image at the center of a div. But the image basically jumps to center after being scaled.
html:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/yellowicon/game-stars/256/Mario-icon.png"/>
</div>
```

Css:

```
div{
    width:400px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Js:

```
$('img').hide().show('scale',{step:function(){
    var el = $(this);
    el.css({
        'top':((el.parent().height() - el.outerHeight())/2),
        'left':((el.parent().width() - el.outerWidth())/2)
    });
}},5000);
```

Edit: Maybe I was not clear in the question, but i WANT TO keep the image in the CENTER of the div always, i.e, during and after animation. And yes, the div is supposed to be wider than the actual image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because an `img` element is `inline` by default. The property `text-align:center` therefore centers it in the middle of the parent `div` element. You could change `text-align` to `left`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/n4Hnq/)

```
div {
    width:400px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Alternatively, change the display of the `img` element to `block` to prevent `text-align` from having an effect on it.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/UsM2X/)

```
img {
    display:block;
}
```

It's also worth noting that you could make this animation with pure CSS:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/KYb64/) - see example for vendor prefixes.

```
div {
    width:400px;
    text-align:left;
    animation:scale 6s forwards;
}

@keyframes scale {
    0% {
        transform:scale(.1);
    }
    100% {
        transform:scale(1);
    }
}
```

---

Edit: If you want the `img` element to be centered the entire time, just change the display to `block` and then add `margin:0 auto`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/5sZax/)

```
div {
    width:400px;
}
img {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: I want to keep it in the center, not align it to the left.

Comment: Doing it in css3 won't guarantee compatibility on older browser, that's why I am using jQuery.

Comment: did you test that? cause in Firefox, the image still resizes while aligned left and then jumps to expected center.

Comment: That's pretty good, but if you look at the effect it is growing towards the center, not from the center

Comment: @user279988 My bad, it's 1:30am here.. i'm tired. Here is an updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/2k5W3/ Unfortunately, `!important` had to be used to overwrite the JS styling. I'm sure it could be avoided though.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `css` and will work fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/H3YHh/2/

Otherwise after your jquery code the css effect `text-align: center` will take effect.

Alternatively, without removing the css use absolute position for the image so that the position top, left would take place as of jquery:

http://jsfiddle.net/H3YHh/5/

```
div{
    width:400px;
    text-align:center;
}
div img{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Positioning it with absolute won't keep it in the center of the parent container. Centering it is the whole point of the question, that's what I wrote the `step` function for.

Comment: So, what about the display: block for the image??

Comment: display block will pretty much end up with the same effect, try for yourself in a fiddle.

Answer (score -1):

You need to calculate the width and height of parent div, and then set the center of image by calculating it from Javascript and it doesn't need CSS3.

```
var s=1;
var ints = setInterval(draw,80);
var dW = $('div').width()/2;
var dH = $('div').height()/2;
 $('img').css({'left':dW+'px','top':dH+'px'});
function draw(){
    s+=2;
    var w = $('img').width()/2;
    var h = $('img').height()/2;
    $('img').css({'width':s+'px','margin-left':-w+'px','margin-top':-h+'px'});
    if(s>=200){
        clearInterval(ints);
    }
}
```

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H3YHh/8/)

Comment: css3 not allowed since I want to maintain compatibility with older browsers.

Comment: do you want image to be scaled from center?

Comment: Yes! Well it needs to be scaled from it's parent's center

Comment: `transform` is a css3 property, I am trying to avoid that. Also if you wanna use css3, you can get the same effect with the `transition` property, you don't need to setup a timer.

Comment: `block` won't put the image in center on it's own. Put a background color on the div to understand what I mean. `text-align:center` works on `inline` elements. Also `margin:auto` will cause the same bug as in my original link.

Comment: @user279988 the answer you've marked as right is not scaling image from center.

Comment: It is the closest usable solution I got